# Initiating pictureinpicture programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, picture-in-picture

[image]I am currently working on a video streaming app that's similar to a simplified version of the Youtube App. I am using AVPictureInPictureController. My problem is when the video is in pip mode, after the video ended, the pip player doesn't initiate the next video thats in line (similar to whats shown in the picture). The only way for me to start the next video is to click on the next video, but then the pip player will go away. How do I stream the next video without closing the pip. Is that possible?

Comment: Please show your current code

Comment: There are too many lines of codes I'm not sure how to show it effectively. My question is ... is it possible to start a pip player programmatically in swift? If so, what is the procedure for that?

Comment: When the video ends - are you detecting a callback from the player?

Comment: Actually yes, when the video is playing in normal view (not pip view), the UI will scroll to the position of the next video and initiate that video. But it doesn't do that when its in pip mode. How do I initiate the next video programmatically and have it play in the pip player that's already open in the bottom right corner?

Comment: Are you responding to a callback to the player? Please post your callback code. It's virtually impossible to help without seeing what code you have, even if it's an entire view controller.

Comment: Upon further examination of the code. I am responding to the callback in normal view, but not in pip mode. After further reading of Apple's documentation, Apple made it clear that you should only trigger this when user press a button. "Picture in Picture (PiP) is a user feature that Apple intends to always be under user control. Invoke PiP only in response to a user’s explicit request to do so. If an app invokes PiP in a way that is not under the immediate direction of the user, it will be rejected by the App Store."

developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller

Comment: Thank you for the help! @quantumpotato